# .Net ListView and System's Icon Size

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I have a ListView using the LargeIcon View mode with some 64x64 thumbnails. The problem is that the padding between ListViewItems is somehow based on the system's Icon size value (Display Properties > Appearance > Advanced > Icon).

The default for XP seems to be 32 and the ListView and its thumbnails look fine, but with higher Icon sizes, the items are spaced out horrendously. Is there any way to override this behavior and force it to use the same spacing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [LVM_SETICONSPACING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761176%28VS.85%29.aspx)